# Loaded "old" Android Studio project - after Studio updates it will no longer open/compile asking for even newer version?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

It has been an year since I last touched my Android Studio project. So after I open Android Studio I am asked to update. After that I am getting a gradle error (I need newer version) so I update that... But now I get:

> Gradle sync failed: This version of Android Studio cannot open this
>   project, please retry with Android Studio 3.5 or newer. (4 m 47 s 83
>   ms)

However - that can hardly be true since I was using version 3.0 and 3.1 earlier and now use 3.3

So... Under "Build Sync" I see error next to

> Build parameterized model 'com.android.builder.model.AndroidProject'
>   for project ':app'

Details:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: This version of Android Studio cannot open
>   this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.5 or newer.  at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.StudioVersions.verifyStudioIsNotOld(StudioVersions.kt:50)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.StudioVersions.verifyStudioIsNotOld(StudioVersions.kt:30)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAndroidProject(ModelBuilder.java:319)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAll(ModelBuilder.java:222)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAll(ModelBuilder.java:138)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$ParameterizedBuildOperationWrappingToolingModelBuilder$1$1.create(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:138)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withLenientState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:132)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$ParameterizedBuildOperationWrappingToolingModelBuilder$1.call(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:134)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$ParameterizedBuildOperationWrappingToolingModelBuilder.buildAll(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:131)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getParameterizedModel(DefaultBuildController.java:99)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:81)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter$2.getModel(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.BuildControllerAdapter.getModel(BuildControllerAdapter.java:62)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncModuleModels.findParameterizedAndroidModel(SyncModuleModels.java:90)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncModuleModels.populate(SyncModuleModels.java:63)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncProjectModels.populateModelsForModule(SyncProjectModels.java:119)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncProjectModels.populateModelsForModule(SyncProjectModels.java:123)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncProjectModels.populate(SyncProjectModels.java:86)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncAction.execute(SyncAction.java:59)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncAction.execute(SyncAction.java:33)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ResultBuildingListener.buildResult(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:114)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ResultBuildingListener.buildFinished(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:106)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:376)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:358)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:346)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:333)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.buildFinished(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:179)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:141)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:83)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

In addition i notice that in my

w:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build.gradle I define various product flavours. However, none appear in the left pane "Build variants". I *hope* it is because it has somehow failed at syncing/parsing...

Comment: The error says to use at least Android Studio 3.5. Open the project in studio preview version or downgrade the build tools to 3.3 if your studio is of that version.

Comment: I can't imagine you should update to a beta version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check your gradle version inside project level gradle

change this

```
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

to the respective version

Comment: You are correct - this worked. I was using "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'"

Answer (score 3):

Please try as follows

- File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Delete .gradle folder
- Restart Android Studio / Re-import the project
- Rebuild & Clean Project